# Avoiding persistence of some methods in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

As it is stated in [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/persistent-classes.html):

> Hibernate persists JavaBeans style properties and recognizes method names of the form getFoo, isFoo and setFoo.

Having following method

```
public boolean isFinished() {
    return (this.dateFinished == null) ? false : true;
}
```

will cause:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at (...)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
(...)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter for property finished in class Order
```

Obviously, if a name of the aforementioned function does not start with `is` everything is fine. So, is it possible to avoid some methods being persisted in a mapped class using e.g. annotations?

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the field with the `@Transient` annotation as stated in the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e432). E.g.,

```
@Transient
public boolean isFinished() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I will say the Hibernate docs do not always make it easy to figure out these sort of things...